# Update Table or drop and recreate?

Tags: android

Hii i have a table in which i have to insert values is only one row..so when the values are updated should i update it or drop it and recreate?SQlite Android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your table has only one row and no row is going to be added then why don't you use `SharedPreference`.  Because integrating with sqlite is somehow heavier operation than working with SharedPreference. And still if you want to use sqlite its preferable to use update. As it will have only one operation than 3 [Drop table, create table and insert a record].